# Can android app beta version and public version exist in the same phone?

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I have an android app published in play store and beta version of app for testing, now the tester don't want to uninstall the published android app from his phone while installing beta version. **How can a tester be able to keep both (public and beta) version in his phone?**

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 app installed with a certain package name.

While developing, you can use a package suffix dependent on build type or flavour which would allow the tester to have 2 apps installed at a certain point, but this would not be published to Play Store. For example, you can have `com.example.mycoolapp` in Play Store and `com.example.mycoolapp.debug` for testing.

I think Play Store beta should only be used when (some) users are ready to receive the new update and give you feedback, but it will just update the already installed app.